# How to place text over sliding images

Tags: html, css, slider

Whenever I run this code on the HTML page, it shows the box with the text on the first sliding image for a brief second, then it disappears for some reason. Here is the HTML for the sliding images.

```css
.containerSlider {
  position: relative;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 150px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="containerSlider">
    <div id="slidingImage">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="image4">
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="slidingImage">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/ffcccc" alt="image1">
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="slidingImage">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="image2">
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="slidingImage">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/ffcccc" alt="image3">
      <div class="text-block">
        <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

and the Javascript for the Slider is

```
<!-- <script src=“https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js”></script> -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#containerSlider').slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The output of your markup doesn't look like a slider. Does it show the problem?

Comment: is there some missing javascript?

Comment: I added the Javascript for the slider if that's the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `position:relative` to the div you want your text to be placed in. In your case, `.containerSlider` contains the complete slider but we want to target individual slides which in this case are `.slidingImage`.

So, after updating your CSS to something like the code below, I believe I got what you wanted.

```css
#slidingImage {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <section>
      <div id="containerSlider">
        <div id="slidingImage">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="image4" />
          <div class="text-block">
            <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slidingImage">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/ffcccc" alt="image1" />
          <div class="text-block">
            <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slidingImage">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="image2" />
          <div class="text-block">
            <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="slidingImage">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/ffcccc" alt="image3" />
          <div class="text-block">
            <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slidingImage {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="slidingImage" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100)">
    <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
</div>
<div class="slidingImage" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100)">
    <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
</div>
<div class="slidingImage" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100)">
    <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
</div>
<div class="slidingImage" style="background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/100)">
    <p>This is a text to see if this works</p>
</div>
```

here